# How to fix QuerySet' object has no attribute 'userrole_set' in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, foreign-keys, django-2.0

When I Adds the specified model objects to the related object set. Like as

My view.py:

```
role = UserRole.objects.get(id=user_role_id)
s = SbTitle.objects.filter(user_role=1)
d = s.userrole_set.add(role) # Associates Entry role with SbTitle s.
```

Then QuerySet' object has no attribute 'userrole_set' error will occur. please tell me how to fix it.

MY model.py:

```
class SbTitle(models.Model):
    sb_title = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True, null=True)
    user_role = models.ForeignKey(UserRole, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.sb_title
```

Comment: The `s` objects already exist, if these are already linked to a `UserRole`, what should happen? Assign these to the new `role`? Or ignore these? Do something else?

Comment: No, I have no link UserRole with s objects

Comment: but `s` is a `QuerySet` of `SbTitle`s, and there is a `user_role = models.ForeignKey(...)`. This relation (likely) spans the relation in reverse. There appears to be no other `userrole_set` or something similar in your model, or at least not as far as we can see.

Comment: I want to be set to multiple objects in the user_role field. How is it possible?

Comment: then you need to use a [**ManyToManyField**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField).

Comment: Please help me with more details !!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223926/discussion-between-m-n-tushar-and-willem-van-onsem).

Comment: the reverse-manager syntax (lowercase model name + '_set') only applies to the model that does not define the relationship (UserRole, in your case). You will never use _set on the model defining the relationship. UserRole is the 'one', SbTitle the 'many', so you can add objects only in the other direction: UserRole_instance.sbtitle_set.add(instance_of_sbtitle)